# Error when using match and indirect in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I have to make a conditional formating formula with cross-sheet references.
Basically I have many sheets, one with existing words, and another one with words we have to add. I want to highlight in "Feuille 6" the words that are already in "Existant". I tried many formulas, I read the doc, I still can't figure it out.

Quick edit : equiv = match, and ligne = row, it's just google sheet translating words into French..

Here's the formula I think I should use, but it's not working

```
=EQUIV(A,indirect("Sheet1!A"&LIGNE()))
```

[Here's what the Feuille 6 looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J27kM.png)

Again, there should be highlighted words in Feuille 6, like " Action ", which already exists in the sheet " Existant ".

I tried replacing "Sheet1 "with "Existant" too.

Any tip please?

Thanks !

Comment: Your EQUIV syntax looks wrong; I don't understand why you need INDIRECT at all; why not COUNTIF ?

Comment: What exactly is wrong in my EQUIV syntax ? Parenthesis are correct, there are 2 arguments, I don't see the mistake here. Using INDIRECT is probably wrong yes, I misread a post on google forums and strongly believed that Indirect was the function to get data from another sheet.. Isn't COUNTIF for numbers and calculations ? I'm just looking to see if 2 string cells match from one sheet to another
Thanks for your help !

Comment: see [Fonction EQUIV](https://support.office.com/fr-fr/article/fonction-equiv-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a).

Comment: Wow you just made me realise that what I thought I needed was wrong, I'm not looking to compare two cells at the exact position, but I want to see if cell A2 from Feuille6 exists somewhere in "Existant", right, I'll try something else then

Comment: The countif is probably what you want. Any zero returned value will be interpreted as false, any non-zero (exists) as true.

Comment: Yes it is, thanks ! And if I want to refer to the whole 'Existant' sheet, is the proper syntax : 'Existant' ? Or 'Existant'!A1:A225 if I want to refer to cells A1 to A225 in Existant ?

Comment: 'Existant'!A:A would be appropriate. e.g. =countif('Existant'!A:A, A1)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Assuming the sheet Existant has values in columns A to Z , and you are highlighting cells in column A

```
 =countif(indirect("Existant!A:Z"), A1)
```

Comment: I tried this one, and "Existant!A1:A225", since I only want the data from column A, with " Custom formula ", it says the formula is not valid. But thanks !

Comment: Hmm, strange.  This is what I have tested, and it works: =countif(indirect("'Existant'!A1:A255"), $A1)

Comment: Still formula not valid. I tried $A1, A1, A2, $A2, but it doesn't work, I can't even save the formula